# C++ Template Error: missing template arguments before ‘=’ token

Tags: c++, templates, struct

I am trying to create a function that sets the root node of a LinkedList. However, when I run the following piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename K>
struct Node {
  Node<K>* next;
  const K value;
};

template <typename K>
Node<K>* root = NULL;

template <typename K>
void SetRoot(const K &key) {
    Node<K> new_node = Node<K> {NULL, key};
    root = &new_node;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     Node<int> n1 = Node<int> {NULL, 48};
     SetRoot(n1);

    return 0;
}
```

I get this error at the line `root = &new_node;`:

> error: missing template arguments before ‘=’ token   root = &new_node;

However, `new_node` does  have all the expected arguments for the struct `Node`.

Comment: Note that with your code, you can only have one list by type...

Comment: Was it you asking a question about template `main` before? May I suggest getting [a good book about templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)? Templates are an advanced topic and they can become a headache without solid foundations.

Comment: Based on your use of `&`, I recommend that you first implement a linked list entirely without templates in order to learn the basics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`root` is a [variable template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template), you need to specify template argument when using it. e.g.

```
root<K> = &new_node;
//  ^^^   specifying K which is the template parameter of SetRoot
```

---

BTW: `new_node` is a local object which will be destroyed when get out of `SetRoot`. After that `root<K>` becomes dangled.